# unable to user the collection.where() in react native due to error

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to query the document's id. I do have the document name and I am using the .where() however it keeps showing the error "Function Query.where() requires a valid third argument, but it was undefined"

```
componentDidMount(name){
        console.log(name)
        dbh.collection('Groups').where("id", "==", name).get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot(doc => {
                this.setState({
                    docID: doc.id
                })
            })
        })

render(){
this.componentDidMount(this.props.route.params.groupName)
return (this.state.docID)
}
```

note that when I am console logging name in the componentDidMount() function, I am getting the name

Answer (score 1):

componentDidMount() gets invoked right after a React component has been mounted.

try this way

```
setDocID(name){
     console.log(name)
     dbh.collection('Groups').where("id", "==", name).get()
     .then(querySnapshot => {
         querySnapshot(doc => {
            this.setState({
                docID: doc.id
            })
          })
      })
}
```

inside the `componentDidMount()` call the above function

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setDocID(this.props.route.params.groupName)
}
```

in the `render()` function you can't render text value without wrapping withing a `Text` component. On the top level import Text component from react-native and wraps the return value.

```
render(){
   return <Text>{this.state.docID}</Text>
}
```